# Lubuntu software centre apps basket - no items displayed

Tags: software-center, lubuntu

I wish to install some programs in Lubuntu (12.10 : i386).
In the  software centre, if I select any app and click "Add to the apps basket", the Apps basket tab shows "Apps basket (1)".
But after visiting the tab "Apps basket (1)", there are no items displayed.
Everything is disabled.

Am I missing something?

Comment: for example, 7zip, IDLE;   no program can be installed.

Comment: it is getting packages. Might take a long time. But it is progressing OK. Should I abort that?

Comment: No! Let it go on. Anyway, you have experience with Ubuntu so just don't panic :)

Comment: finally, "Reading package lists... Done". And now I can install the software in software centre. Thanks for your help. You can put your reply in "Answer" and I will "Accept" it. Thanks again.

Comment: You did the hard work! You can answer the question yourself and accept your own answer, perhaps after a while. Nothing wrong with doing so.  Also, **don't forget to edit your question** to make it clear that you couldn't install any software, not just certain ones.